# Update a Status Column Automatically

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am creating a library management application with a membership form.

Types of Membership are:

1. Half yearly
2. Annually
3. Patron(For 15 Minutes)
4. Life Member

Now I have designed a table in SQL SERVER 2008 which consists of:

1. MemberId
2. Name
3. Joining Date
4. Expiration Date
5. Status

The status consists of either `M` for Member or `E` for Expired Membership.

Now I want this task to happen automatically.

For example, if the expiration date of membership was yesterday then it should automatically change the status to `E`.

How can I do this?

Comment: No need for the extra exclamation points. People are reading these questions in the hopes of helping you out :)

Comment: Can you update your question title to not be so ambiguous?

Answer (score 3):

Use an expiration date of `NULL` to be your Life Member memberships. Then, [create a SQL Server Agent job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135739.aspx) which kicks off the following statement and runs every 15 minutes (or 5):

```
UPDATE 
    Membership 
SET 
    Status = 'E' 
WHERE 
    Status = 'M' AND ExpirationDate < getdate() 
    AND ExpirationDate IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a computed column?

Inside the table designer select your status column, go to the column properties and select the node "computed column specification". Enter the formula there:

```
CASE WHEN ExpirationDate IS NOT NULL AND ExpirationDate < GETDATE() THEN 'E' ELSE 'M' END
```

The only negative thing about this is, that it cannot be indexed.

Comment: I would think you'd want this indexed for rapid retrieval of active members, eh? Also remember that the calc is run for every row whenever a new query is called on it, which could hinder performance as the table gets larger.

Comment: An index would be of no use on this column since the selectivity would be so low.

Answer (score 0):

You could [create a SQL Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx) and [schedule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645912.aspx) it to run every night to update the status flag. Here's an [overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187880.aspx) to get you started on it.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're treating your database as an independent datasource with this requirement. It looks to be more of a business case to update this status flag. What happens if you update the Expiration date later on? You'll also have to update that status flag. You might want your application to interpret the Expiration Date instead.

Thanks,
-tom

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Actually I have not installed Sql server agent.

Can you tell me the link where SQL SERVER AGENT is availalbe as FreeWare?

Please help me out!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading your record into an object, why not use the properties of the object to show you "member"/"expired"?

This kind of automatic operation isn't really suited to a persistent data store.  ou can use the computed columns as Greco suggested if you really need it, ut it is rightly pointed out that this can develop into a performance issue.